# How to call an asyncData or fetch hook again in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello I want to recall asyncData function in methods or another solution when do the call api because i want to do a `$emit` when call this action which resets data
I do that but is don't work

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
    <my-orders
     :orders="orders
      @sendData="initOrders"
    />
</template>
<script>
 async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const orders = await endpoint.getOrders({ $axios });
    return {
      orders
    };
  },
 methods: {
   async initOrders() {
      await this.asyncData
    },
}
</script>
```

Please help thank you

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions/9277#discussioncomment-721283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$nuxt.refresh()` can help you re-fetch any `fetch()` or `asyncData()` hooks.